# List and Strings

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, slice

I am new to Python. Can you please help me in explaining this:

```
>>> list2 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(list2[1:-1])
[2]
>>> print(str(list2)[1:-1])
1, 2, 3
```

Why is the slicing result different when the list is changed to string?

Comment: Have you looked at the string *without* slicing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slicing applies to the individual elements of the sequence you are slicing, returning a new object of the same type you sliced containing the selected elements.

Your list contains integers, slicing produces a new list containing the selected integers. A string contains *characters*, so slicing a string produces a new string with the selected characters.

Where your list contains just 3 elements (the integers `1`, `2` and `3`), your string contains far more elements, namely the characters `'['`, `'1'`, `' '` (a space), `','` (a comma), `'2'`, `' '`, `','`, etc., all the way to `']'` at the end. Note that those elements are not integers, and that there is no special meaning assigned to the `,` characters, and that spaces count as characters too. The string contains 9 characters in total.

So when you slice the list removing the first and last element, only one element remains, the integer `2`. But slicing the string removes the `'['` (the first character) and `']'`, leaving the remaining string `'1, 2, 3'`, 7 characters in total.

If you let the interpreter echo these objects (rather than use `print()`) it might be clearer:

```
>>> list2 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list2
[1, 2, 3]
>>> len(list2)
3
>>> str(list2)
'[1, 2, 3]'
>>> len(str(list2))
9
>>> list2[1:-1]
[2]
>>> len(list2[1:-1])
1
>>> str(list2)[1:-1]
'1, 2, 3'
>>> len(str(list2)[1:-1])
7
```

Note the `'` quotes around the string objects.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are also iterables which can be sliced:

```
>>> "abcde"[1:-1]
'bcd'
```

And the string representation of a list is the elements of the list, separated by commas, wrapped in brackets:

```
>>> str(list2)
'[1, 2, 3]'
```

Therefore, when you drop<sup>†</sup> the first and last entries in the iterable string `"[1, 2, 3]"`, you get the string `"1, 2, 3"` (not, as it would appear when you `print` it, the list):

```
>>> str(list2)[1:-1]
'1, 2, 3'
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Remember, in Python you can use negative indicies to work from the *last* entry in the iterable to the first, so `[1:-1]` is equivalent to `[1:len(iterable) - 1]`.  That is, every element from the *second* to the second-to-last.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

`[1:-1]` means slicing from the first element to the second-to-last element. When slicing `list2` directly, it takes away the first and last elements (1 and 3), and all that is left is the middle element `[2]`.

In python, strings are also considered iterables; each character can be thought of as an element. The string form of `list2` is `'[1, 2, 3]'`. Thus when you remove the first and last characters (left and right brackets), you are left with the substring `'1, 2, 3'`.